# Pandas selecting the column name based on row information

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I am using Pandas and Python 3.5.1.

Please assume a DataFrame of the following, named `df`:

```
    name1  name2  name3  name4
0     1      2      3      4
1     5      6      7      8
2     4      9      6      2
3     5      1      7      3
```

Note that all values in each row are unique, no column has the same value as another on a row by row basis.

Say I have a number in my sights, `7` from `df[name3][1]`, for example. Is there a way to get only the column header, `name3`, based on the row`(1)` and value`(7)`?

I do not want anything in the column itself such as `3, 7, 6, or 7`. I only want the column header.

Comment: And there can't be duplicates? (just checking again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General solution - working if not match `row` or `val`:

```
val = 70
row = 10

val = df.reindex(index=[row]).eq(val).squeeze()
col = next(iter(val.index[val]), 'no match')
print (col)
no match
```

Another general solution:

```
def get_col(row, val):
    try:
        a = df.loc[row].eq(val)
        c = a.index[a][0]
    except KeyError:
        c = 'not matched row'
    except IndexError:
        c = 'not matched value'
    return c

print (get_col(1, 7))
name3
print (get_col(10, 7))
not matched row
print (get_col(1, 70))
not matched value
print (get_col(10, 70))
not matched row
```

Solution if **always exist val** and row values in `DataFrame`, because if not exist and all Falses are returned from `df.loc[row].eq(val)` then `idxmax` return first `False` - first column name.

```
val = 7
row = 1
col = df.loc[row].eq(val).idxmax()
#if want seelct by pocition use iloc
#col = df.iloc[row].eq(val).idxmax()
print (col)
name3
```

**Explanation**:

First select row by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc[row])
name1    5
name2    6
name3    7
name4    8
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Then compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html)

```
print (df.loc[row].eq(val))
name1    False
name2    False
name3     True
name4    False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

And last get index value of first `True` by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
print (df.loc[row].eq(val).idxmax())
name3
```

Comment: Yes but.. better use iloc here. ( I think)

Comment: @jezrael ``df.iloc[row].eq(val).idxmax()`` worked wonderfully, I plugged it in my program and I am ready to go. Thank you very much! Also, I appreciate the explanation and comments.

Comment: @Spigot - Super, glad can help. Only one thing - there has to always exist value `val`, because if not exist it return first column name. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method to get what you want.
For example:

```
maps = [[],[(0,'name1'),(3,'name2')],[(0,'name2'),(2,'name4')],... ]
```

When you choose `1 from df[name1][0]` you will find `maps[1] = [(0,'name1'),(3,'name2')]` And you can get the col name where `row = 0` is `name1`

The whole code like this:

```
maps = [(),() ..... ]
for col in data.columns:
    for row in range(len(data)):
        value = data[col][row]
        maps[value] = (row,col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to loop through the key,values and use next.

```
lookup = 14
row = 1
next((k for k,v in df.iloc[row,:].items() if v == lookup), 'No match')
```